# How can I enable SSL for Amazon RDS Mysql in Spring Boot / Spring Data?

Tags: mysql, ssl, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-rds

Currently the spring boot app using spring data is configured to use a non-encrypted connection to an Amazon RDS instance.  I want to prevent eavesdropping of the data in transport so I want to enable SSL between the app and the database instance.

My connection is setup using the stock properties available in spring boot.

in my application.properties I use the following to setup the database connection.

```
spring.datasource.catalog=MYDB
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://INSTANCEURL/${spring.datasource.catalog}?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
```

Despite using the URI variables that enable SSL on the URL the configuration to specify the PEM file provided by amazon to encrypt the connections is unknown.

Ideally I would prefer an embedded solution for access to the certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, embedding the security certificate is an anti-pattern and instead the certificate is installed into a path and then referenced inside of the JVM.

Comment: So how did you added/refereed  pem file provided by AWS in connection string ? Did you added any system property?